# Why are my TextFormFields breaking and causing excessive rebuilds?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, riverpod

I have been struggling with debugging why nearly all of my `TextField`s and `TextFormField`s are breaking in my Flutter app. By *breaking*, I mean:

1. I am unable to focus on or enter a value into a Text(Form)Field without the field automatically unfocusing and causing flickering across the screen (which I assume is a consequence of excessive building).
2. My RiverPod states behave unexpectedly, causing changes in states that do not make sense.

I would assume that the latter of these issues is a consequence of some error which can be resolved by fixing the former. One of the situations where this error arises is in a widget I made called `VerifyAlert`, which displays a `TextField` and Ok/Cancel action buttons in an `AlertDialog`. Here is the implementation:

```
class VerifyAlert extends StatefulWidget {
  const VerifyAlert({
    super.key,
    this.message = 'Verify',
    this.confirmMessage = 'Ok',
    this.cancelMessage = 'Cancel',
    required this.onVerification,
    required this.onFailedVerification,
    required this.verifier,
  });

  final String message; // body text
  final String confirmMessage; // confirm button text
  final String cancelMessage; // cancel button text
  final AsyncCallback onVerification;
  final AsyncCallback onFailedVerification;
  final Function(String) verifier;

  @override
  State<VerifyAlert> createState() => _VerifyAlertState();
}

class _VerifyAlertState extends State<VerifyAlert> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        widget.message,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 24.0,
        ),
      ),

      //* Auth Password
      content: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
          hintText: 'Empty',
        ),
        autocorrect: false,
        autofocus: false,
      ),

      actions: [
        TextButton(
          child: Text(
            widget.cancelMessage,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17.5,
              color: ui.LightScheme.blue,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.onFailedVerification();
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            if (widget.verifier(_controller.text)) {
              if (context.mounted) {
                widget.onVerification();
              }
            } else {
              if (context.mounted) {
                widget.onFailedVerification();
              }
            }
          },
          child: Text(
            widget.confirmMessage,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17.5,
              color: ui.LightScheme.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have another method for showing this alert:

```
Future<void> showVerifyAlert({
  required BuildContext context,
  String message = '',
  String confirmMessage = 'Ok',
  String cancelMessage = 'Cancel',
  required AsyncCallback onVerification,
  required AsyncCallback onFailedVerification,
  required Function(String) verifier,
}) async {
  return await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return VerifyAlert(
        message: message,
        confirmMessage: confirmMessage,
        cancelMessage: cancelMessage,
        onVerification: onVerification,
        onFailedVerification: onFailedVerification,
        verifier: verifier,
      );
    },
    barrierDismissible: true,
  );
}
```

I have verified before that this scheme of constructing custom alerts works, so the issue is definitely with the way my `TextFormField`. Also, this is not the only instance where a `TextField` or `TextFormField` breaks in my application; nearly all non-trivial implementations of Text(Form)Field suffer from the same issue.

My environment is an M1 Macbook Pro, iOS Simulator running iOS 16.4 emulating an iPad (10th Generation), and Flutter 3.14.0-0.1.pre with Dart SDK version: 3.2.0-42.1.beta.

I tried to re-implement my Text(Form)Fields without a `TextEditingController`, but the problem still remained. In the context of the example given previously, I rewrote the `TextFormField` to have no `controller` and, instead, to have an `onChanged` method which set the state of a string which stored the current value in the input, which I could then use in the `verifier` method.

I have also tried to use `ValueKey`s in my fields, but this has also failed.

Previously, I had a very similar problem with one of my `TextFormField`s, and all I did was move to the Flutter beta channel, install an XCode update, and restart my computer, and without changing my code at all, the TextFormField now worked. This was very strange, but I ignored it for the time being. Now, this problem has permeated nearly all of my Text(Form)Fields, and so, I am unable to ascertain whether or not this is a problem with my code or a problem with my environment.

Having spent nearly a week on this issue, I hope someone in this community can help. Thanks.

**Update 1**

I built another application with this `VerifyAlert` widget, and it worked as expected, so I am inclined to believe this is an issue with the way Flutter is either focusing or building my Text(Form)Fields. This same issue is prevalent in both iOS and Android emulators of all types, and on my physical device.

The only major difference between my actual application and the application I built to test `VerifyAlert` is that in the former, I am showing my alert after two layers of pushed contexts (i.e., I've called `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(...))` twice before I show my alert). I am inclined to believe that it is some behavior confused from these contexts that is causing the bug I am experiencing.

As a suggestion recommended, I've attached the code which triggers this `VerifyAlert`:

```
class RecordsView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RecordsView({
    super.key,
    this.record,
    required this.accessType,
  });

  final Map<String, dynamic>? record;
  final RecordAccess accessType;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _RecordsViewState();
}

class _RecordsViewState extends ConsumerState<RecordsView> {
  //* Method for initializing record and returning a Future<bool> of whether or not it was successful
  Future<bool> initializeRecord(
    SelectedForm selectedForm,
    User user,
  ) async {
    try {
      if (widget.accessType == RecordAccess.create) {
        Map<String, dynamic> formData =
            await network.NetworkUtility.fetchFormDetails(
          accessToken: user.accessToken,
          formId: selectedForm.id.toString(),
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> pagesData =
            await network.NetworkUtility.fetchFormPageDetails(
          formId: selectedForm.id.toString(),
          accessToken: user.accessToken,
        );

        if (Record.isCreateValid(formData: formData, pagesData: pagesData)) {
          ref.read(recordProvider.notifier).clear();
          ref.read(recordProvider.notifier).create(
                formData: formData,
                pagesData: pagesData,
                accessType: widget.accessType,
              );
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (widget.record == null) {
          return false;
        } else {
          int formId = selectedForm.id;

          if (selectedForm.id == -1) {
            try {
              formId = widget.record!['form'] as int;
            } catch (e) {
              return false;
            }
          }

          Map<String, dynamic> formData =
              await network.NetworkUtility.fetchFormDetails(
            accessToken: user.accessToken,
            formId: formId.toString(),
          );

          Map<String, dynamic> pagesData =
              await network.NetworkUtility.fetchFormPageDetails(
            formId: formId.toString(),
            accessToken: user.accessToken,
          );

          if (Record.isLoadValid(
            formData: formData,
            pagesData: pagesData,
            recordData: widget.record!,
          )) {
            ref.read(recordProvider.notifier).clear();
            ref.read(recordProvider.notifier).load(
                  formData: formData,
                  pagesData: pagesData,
                  recordData: widget.record!,
                  accessType: widget.accessType,
                );

            if (ref
                .read(recordProvider)
                .auth['password']
                .toString()
                .isNotEmpty) {
              bool verified = false;
              if (context.mounted) {
                await ui.showVerifyAlert(
                  context: GlobalKeys.alpha.currentContext!,
                  message: 'Enter Password',
                  onVerification: () {
                    verified = true;
                  },
                  onFailedVerification: () {},
                  verifier: (value) {
                    return value ==
                        ref.read(recordProvider).auth['password'].toString();
                  },
                );
              }

              return verified;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Widget closableContent(
    BuildContext context,
    Widget centerWidget,
  ) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.close, size: ui.Text.scale(context, 36)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: centerWidget,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final selectedForm = ref.watch(selectedFormProvider);
    final user = ref.watch(userProvider);

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
            false, // ensures that the keyboard does not push UI elements up
        backgroundColor: ui.LightScheme.gray,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(ui.Text.scale(context, 21, 3)),

            //* All Content is in SafeArea and Padded
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: initializeRecord(selectedForm, user),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (snapshot.data!) {
                    return const RecordVisualizer();
                  } else {
                    return closableContent(
                      context,
                      const Text('Authentication Failed. Please try again.'),
                    );
                  }
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return closableContent(
                    context,
                    const Text('Could not load record. Please try again.'),
                  );
                } else {
                  return closableContent(
                    context,
                    const ui.FourDotsLoadingIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget is pushed on top of another widget, which itself is also pushed onto the first widget in the widget tree. Perhaps this is the reason behind my bug, but I am still unable to determine how to proceed from here. This issue is likely not originating from anything in Riverpod, as `VerifyAlert` breaks even when there is nothing related to Riverpod embedded in its logic. I would appreciate any additional comments and guidance, and thank you once again.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: try to reproduce the problem with a minimal "hello world" Flutter app (no Riverpod, "nothing fancy").  If it works OK, try methodically adding an "element at a time" to see if you can "break" your test app.  Please post back what you learn; please update your post with any additional questions along the way.  ALSO: Does the problem occur on other Flutter devices (e.g. web page, or a physical handset)?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Its impossible to reproduce this without knowing all the methods and what your Riverpod setup looks like.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you for your suggestions. I tried reproducing the issue, and I've included my new insights into an update of my original post. I have also included more code, as was recommended by Code on the Rocks. I think there might be some simple rendering bug going on somewhere, but I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out why this problem was happening, and I think posting an answer would be instructive for anyone running into similar issues in the future, especially since there is no clear error Flutter provides for such behavior and it is not something easily identifiable by just observing one's code.

There were two primary issues in my code:

1. **Media Queries:** I was using custom media queries to size parts of the UI. For some reason, whenever a TextField is active in particularly complex UI arrangements (which may just happen accidentally), the media query for resizing your UI is called over and over again, causing repeated builds and make your app work entirely unpredictably. The best way to diagnose if this is your issue is to first *check how many times your `build()` function is executing* (add a `print('built')` inside it, for example), and if it is building excessively, **replace your media queries with the [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package**.
2. **Riverpod & TextField Focus Returning:** A problem was happening in another part of my code involving TextFields where a Riverpod state change would cause the TextField's focus to return to the previous TextField upon which the user was focused. The only way I was able to resolve this issue was by adding a `FocusNode` to each TextField widget and by wrapping the TextField in a GestureDetector which had the following function inside it:

```
onTap: () {
  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focus);
}
```

Here, `_focus` refers to a private `FocusNode` attribute. What this does is to force the current focus to be cleared and assigns the focus back to your `TextField`, which should behave just like a `TextField` normally would; but, for some reason, it doesn't and instead fixes this issue with `Riverpod` and `TextFields` interacting in an undesirable manner.